# How to add a message handler to a wndproc

Tags: winapi

I have an acrobat plugin which spins up a thread. From that thread I somehow need to get back onto the UI thread. I do have the HWND but if I do a `PostMessage` how do I get the host application's WNDPROC to sort of call bank into an handler I own. I guess my question is, is there anyway to conceptually do something like

```
RegisterWndMsgHandler( HWND, MSG, CALLBACK );
```

Comment: You cannot get the host window to handle a message it wasn't written to handle.  Create your own window in the code that "spins up a thread".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the `HWND` by replacing its message handler with your own via `SetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)`.  By sure to call `GetWindowLongPtr(GWL_WNDPROC)` to retreive the original handler, and then have your handler pass any unhandled messages to `CallWindowProc()` so the original handler can process them.

Comment: yeah figured this out on my own but this works like a charm, this is really very cool I should be able to use this to do background processing for Outlook addins as well

Comment: one thing I would add though us that you don't need to call GetWindowLongPtr, SetWindowLongPtr returns the value at the offset ( in this case GWL_WNDPROC) so you just store the return value from SetWindowLongPtr  to use in CallWindowProc