# WinApi Win32 Programming - Button click not sending WM_COMMAND message

Tags: c, winapi, window

I have been working on a tab controlled program for awhile now and have only recently been posting on StackOverflow for help.  Currently the program runs as follows:

1. Begin in `winMain`, Creation of `main_hwnd` generates `WM_CREATE` and `wndProc` is called
2. `tab_hwnd` is created as a `SysTabControl32`
3. `tab0_hwnd`, `tab1_hwnd`, ..., `tab4_hwnd` are created

   - In `tab0_hwnd`, static text and buttons are created
4. Return to `winMain` and `ShowWindow()` is called on `main_hwnd`, `tab_hwnd` and `tab0_hwnd`
5. Enter a loop until program is closed.

When the program is run, everything is visible; however, the buttons do not function properly.  At the same time, when I was searching for errors using `GetLastError()` and `FormatMessage()` I found that after creating windows `tab#_hwnd` (where # = 0,1,2,3 and 4), the following error appears:

Error 6: The handle is Invalid

I am not sure as to why this error appears and why the button does not work.  Another user has suggested the following in a previous post:

"`WM_COMMAND` is sent to immediate parent window, not to grandparents, so you'll either have to subclass your tab controls too, or make your buttons have your main window as parent." - Anton Kovalenko

Edit 1: I am unsure how to subclass my tab controls as suggested by Anton Kovalenko.  Any links to tutorials/explanations to comments would be extremely helpful.

Here is the current code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

#define ID_FILE_EXIT                    101
#define ID_HELP_ABOUT                   102
#define ID_B_BLANK                      1001
#define ID_B_HOME                       1002
#define ID_B_SAVE                       1003

#include <strsafe.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ShlObj.h>

HWND main_hwnd, tab_hwnd, tab0_hwnd, tab1_hwnd, tab2_hwnd, tab3_hwnd, tab4_hwnd;
HINSTANCE tab_hinst;
TCHAR HomePath[MAX_PATH*2], SavePath[MAX_PATH*2];
WNDCLASSEX wc;
bool success=FALSE;
MSG msg;
HWND button;
static HWND text;
TCITEM tie;
int focus = 0, NotifyCase = 0;

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction) 
{ 
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw); 
}
// Call with ErrorExit(TEXT("ANYTHINGHERE"));

    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            {
                tab_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 681, 338,
                    hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                tab0_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    1, 22, 679, 315,
                    tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                //ErrorExit(TEXT("HERE")); //<--- This gives error 6: Handle invalid

                text = CreateWindow("Static","Home Directory",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,0,50,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
                text = CreateWindow("Static","C:\\",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,200,50,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
                button = CreateWindow("Button","Navigate to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,42,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_HOME,tab_hinst,0);  
                text = CreateWindow("Static","Save Directory",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,0,100,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
                text = CreateWindow("Static","C:\\",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,200,100,150,50,tab0_hwnd, 0, tab_hinst,0);
                button = CreateWindow("Button","Save to...", BS_PUSHBUTTON | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE ,350,92,100,25,tab0_hwnd,(HMENU)ID_B_SAVE,tab_hinst,0);

                tab1_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    1, 22, 679, 315,
                    tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                tab2_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    1, 22, 679, 315,
                    tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                tab3_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    1, 22, 679, 315,
                    tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                tab4_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
                    0,
                    "SysTabControl32",
                    "",
                    WS_CHILD,
                    1, 22, 679, 315,
                    tab_hwnd, NULL, tab_hinst, NULL);

                tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
                tie.pszText = "Paths";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 0, &tie);
                tie.pszText = "Output";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 1, &tie);
                tie.pszText = "Parameters";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 2, &tie);
                tie.pszText = "Configurations";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 3, &tie);
                tie.pszText = "Run";
                TabCtrl_InsertItem(tab_hwnd, 4, &tie);

                HMENU hMenu, hSubMenu;

                hMenu = CreateMenu();

                hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&File");
                AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_FILE_EXIT, "&Exit");

                hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
                AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "&Help");
                AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_HELP_ABOUT, "&About");

                SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);
            }
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch(((LPNMHDR)lParam) ->code)
            {
                case TCN_SELCHANGING:
                    switch(TabCtrl_GetCurFocus(tab_hwnd))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ShowWindow(tab1_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ShowWindow(tab2_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ShowWindow(tab3_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ShowWindow(tab4_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
                            break;
                        default:
                            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case TCN_SELCHANGE:
                    switch(TabCtrl_GetCurFocus(tab_hwnd))
                    {
                        case 0:
                            ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            ShowWindow(tab1_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            ShowWindow(tab2_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            ShowWindow(tab3_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            ShowWindow(tab4_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
                            break;
                        default:
                            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            //MessageBox(tab0_hwnd,"HERE","OKAY",NULL);
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case ID_FILE_EXIT:
                    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case ID_HELP_ABOUT:
                    return MessageBox(0, "This program is an alteration of ...", "About", MB_OK);
                case ID_B_HOME:
                    if(BN_CLICKED == HIWORD(wParam)){
                        MessageBox(tab0_hwnd,"HERE","OKAY",NULL);
                    }
                    break;
                case ID_B_SAVE:
                    if(BN_CLICKED == HIWORD(wParam)){
                    }
                    break;
                case ID_B_BLANK:
                    break;
                default:
                    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;  
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    InitCommonControls();
    tab_hinst = hInstance;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = "Home";
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

    main_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        "Home",
        "The Home page",
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 700, 400,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(main_hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(main_hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(tab_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
    ShowWindow(tab0_hwnd,SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(main_hwnd);

    do{
        PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    } while(msg.message!=WM_CLOSE && msg.message!=WM_QUIT);
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Anton Kovalenko's comment exactly explains what is wrong and what you need to fix.

Comment: I thought his comment only explained the button not working. Does it also explain the invalid handle error?

Comment: I was under the impression that the text input into `ErrorExit()` sole purpose was to be placed into the `MessageBox()` the function calls.  I just grabbed this function from MSDN to handle errors so as to simplify my life.

Comment: I am hedging bets on the `LocalFree` for the buffer by the `FormatMessage`, try comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: t0mm13b, What exactly are you suggesting I comment out? I'm confused by your statement. If it was to comment out these lines:
    `LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);`
it didn't change anything.

Comment: I am guessing (been a long time so bit rustic on Win32API) but, is the buffer NULL, the one that holds the error message via `FormatMessage` function.. that could give way to invalid handle as the memory occupied by the buffer may be NULL...just a thought... I do not see a check if that was a successful call...

Comment: Not sure, but wouldn't that return the same Error 6: Handle invalid every time I call the function? When I call it in a different setting, it doesn't have any errors.

Comment: I'm not sure that `GetLastError` is supposed to make any sense unless it's *known* that a function has failed. And if `CreateWindowEx` returns a handle, then it didn't fail.

Comment: If the function succeeded (as yours did), then the value returned by `GetLastError()` is meaningless.  You need to process the `WM_COMMAND` messages in the container windows. This is easier if you use a custom class instead of abusing a tab control. If you want to go ahead with the subclassing approach, then just do it. [Here's one example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13253285/).

Comment: I agree, I just ran a quick if statement saying if it was NULL, output a MessageBox. Nothing appeared. So then all that's left is to understand how to Subclass the `tab#_hwnd` handles.

Comment: I cannot find a good explanation on how to use `SetWindowLongPtr()`, `GetWindowLongPtr()` and `CallWindowProc()`.  I believe set will capture the current wndProc message and create a pointer to it that Get will receive, and call will return the message back to wndProc... but i'm not sure.  And if it is right, I'm not sure where in a code to place these functions.